# How can I fix a "could not resolve dependency" error with firebase, exceljs and emailjs?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, exceljs

I am trying to run `emailjs` but have been receiving the following errors for a while. Can someone please tell me what I did wrong?

I installed `exceljs` with the force flag, as in the following statement

```
  npm install exceljs --force
```

But I am receiving the following error message:

```
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: job-seeking-folder@0.0.0
npm WARN Found: firebase@10.8.1
npm WARN node_modules/firebase
npm WARN   peer firebase@">= 9.0.0" from react-firebase-hooks@5.1.1
npm WARN   node_modules/react-firebase-hooks
npm WARN     react-firebase-hooks@"^5.1.1" from the root project   
npm WARN   1 more (the root project)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer firebase@">= 9.0.0" from react-firebase-hooks@5.1.1  
npm WARN node_modules/react-firebase-hooks
npm WARN   react-firebase-hooks@"^5.1.1" from the root project     
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for firebase@^13.3.1.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-03-08T22_55_58_263Z-debug
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because npm cannot find the requested package version. The firebase package's ^13.3.1 version is not available. This error typically occurs in the following situations:

Incorrect package name or version number: The package name or version number may have been incorrectly written. Check the correct package name and version number.

Package removal or relocation: The desired version may no longer be available due to the package being removed or relocated. In this case, try using another available version or update your dependencies.